# Matrix inverse of a square matrix that is the product of rectangular matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, pseudoinverse

Suppose I have an $m\times n$ matrix $A$ and an $n\times m$ matrix $B$, with $m<n$, and the $m\times m$ matrix $AB$ is invertible. I know $B^+B=1_{m\times m}=AA^+$, where $^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse. Because $AB$ is invertible, I also know $(AB)^{-1}=(AB)^+$, and specifically, $(AB)^{-1}(AB)=1_{m\times m}$. However, because $m<n$, it is NOT true that $(AB)^+=B^+A^+$. Is there a manageable way to write $(AB)^{-1}$?

I know that in the case I stated above, $B^+=(B^TB)^{-1}B^T$ and $A^+=A^T(AA^T)^{-1}$, but I don't know if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem can be restated in that you are given two sets $A^T$ and $B$ of $m$ column vectors
in $\mathbb R ^n$, and you know the resulting matrix $A B$ of their mutual dot products.

The expression of $(AB)^-1$ in terms of $A$ and $B$ depends on what is your final goal, but I deem that a
possily interesting way would be through their QR or SVD decomposition .